# Uncaught Reference Error Inf is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wcf

So I'm using a WCF with this method:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
MathResult DoMath(double n1, double n2);
```

One of the elements of MathResult is the quotient... Any when you divide by 0 that number becomes infinitely large.

The WCF returns this field with the value of INF.

This causes issues and I get the "Uncaught ReferenceError: INF is not defined" error.

Here is the JSON it's returning (if n1 = 1 and n2 = 0):

```
{"__type":"MathResult:#Microsoft.Samples.ComplexTypeAjaxService","difference":1,"product":0,"quotient":INF,"sum":1}
```

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var derp = function(result)
    {
        $("#output").text(result.sum);
    }

    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        var myurl = "http://localhost:54111/service.svc/DoMath";
        $.ajax({
            url: myurl,
            data: { n1: $("#txt1").val(), n2: $("#txt2").val() },
            type: 'GET',
            success: derp,
            error: function(){ alert("Oh ****"); },
            dataType: 'jsonp'
        });
    });
});
```

Here's the data contract:

```
[DataContract]
public class MathResult
{
    [DataMember]
    public double sum;

    [DataMember]
    public double difference;

    [DataMember]
    public double product;

    [DataMember]
    public double quotient;
}
```

It works with any other value it returns.

Comment: That's invalid JSON.  There is no `INF` token in JSON.

Comment: So what do you suggest that I do?

Comment: Log a bug with whomever's responsible for that code. Solid server-side JSON encoder libraries would not make that mistake.

Comment: That would be Microsoft's WCF code lol... I guess I'll log a bug with MS.

Comment: Ha ha - well, it really is a bug. It should either throw an exception during the encoding if it thinks it can't successfully encode the value, or else it should pick some valid JSON value (`null` maybe? There's no `NaN` in JSON either). What it should **not** do is emit something that's going to cause a parsing error at some point in the future.

Answer (score 0):

INF in this case means INFINITY - so it seems that somewhere in your logic there is a division by zero...